# AEM JCR SQL2 query to find all pages contains specific component

Tags: sql, xpath, aem, jcr

I wish to build a sql2 jcr query to find all pages under `/content` that contains this component, e.g `/apps/platform/aem-core/components/content/form/form`

I read https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/JCR+Query+Cheat+Sheet and tried something like below

My current attempt is something like `SELECT * from [cq:Page] AS t WHERE t.contains('/apps/platform/aem-core/components/content/form/form')`

But it won't work. Please suggest me a example to find all pages contains this component. Thanks

Comment: if you are on AEM you may want to use QueryBuilder - https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-api.html  api. It provides additional capabilities and ease of use by providing predicates for commonly used searches.

Answer (score 0):

As @awd has mentioned in the comments, `QueryBuilder` provides better capabilities.

`SQL2` however is not that bad, especially for someone with an inclination towards RDBMS !

The below query should fetch all the page paths using the component resourceType.

> SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] AS s WHERE
>   ISDESCENDANTNODE(s,'/content') AND CONTAINS(s.[sling:resourceType],
>   'foundation/components/text')

You've got to use square brackets for properties with namespaces in them, for e.g: cq:template, sling:resourceType, etc

Answer (score 0):

SELECT page.* FROM [cq:Page] AS page INNER JOIN [nt:base] AS component ON ISDESCENDANTNODE(component,page) WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(page, '/content') AND component.[sling:resourceType] = '/apps/platform/aem-core/components/content/form/form'

Comment: Could you improve the formatting for your code?

Answer (score 0):

select * from nt:base where jcr:path like '/content/%' and [sling:resourceType] ='/apps/platform/aem-core/components/content/form/form'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).